# NVMe very slow speeds INTEL SSDPEKNW512G8L

Tags: mount, nvme, sddm, hdparm

need some help to identify why this disk is running so slow:

```
sudo hdparm -tT /dev/sda

/dev/sda:
 Timing cached reads:   1962 MB in  2.00 seconds = 982.96 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads:  90 MB in  3.03 seconds =  29.68 MB/sec
```

but

```
pi@raspberrypi:/ $ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/samba/tempfile bs=1M count=4096 conv=fdatasync,notrunc status=progress oflag=direct
skopiowane 1048576 bajtów (1,0 MB, 1,0 MiB), 17 s, **61,1 kB/s**
```

```
lsusb
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:9210 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL9210 M.2 NVME Adapter
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 214b:7250 Huasheng Electronics USB2.0 HUB
```

```
pi@raspberrypi:/ $ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [aarch64-linux-6.1.21-v8+] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Number:                       INTEL SSDPEKNW512G8L
Serial Number:                      BTNH93310F9Y512A
Firmware Version:                   L02C
PCI Vendor/Subsystem ID:            0x8086
IEEE OUI Identifier:                0x5cd2e4
Controller ID:                      1
NVMe Version:                       1.3
Number of Namespaces:               1
Namespace 1 Size/Capacity:          512 110 190 592 [512 GB]
Namespace 1 Formatted LBA Size:     512
Namespace 1 IEEE EUI-64:            5cd2e4 3891c09b51
Local Time is:                      Sun May 21 12:47:44 2023 CEST
Firmware Updates (0x14):            2 Slots, no Reset required
Optional Admin Commands (0x0017):   Security Format Frmw_DL Self_Test
Optional NVM Commands (0x005f):     Comp Wr_Unc DS_Mngmt Wr_Zero Sav/Sel_Feat Timestmp
Log Page Attributes (0x0f):         S/H_per_NS Cmd_Eff_Lg Ext_Get_Lg Telmtry_Lg
Maximum Data Transfer Size:         32 Pages
Warning  Comp. Temp. Threshold:     77 Celsius
Critical Comp. Temp. Threshold:     80 Celsius

Supported Power States
St Op     Max   Active     Idle   RL RT WL WT  Ent_Lat  Ex_Lat
 0 +     3.50W       -        -    0  0  0  0        0       0
 1 +     2.70W       -        -    1  1  1  1        0       0
 2 +     2.00W       -        -    2  2  2  2        0       0
 3 -   0.0250W       -        -    3  3  3  3     5000    5000
 4 -   0.0040W       -        -    4  4  4  4     5000    9000

Supported LBA Sizes (NSID 0x1)
Id Fmt  Data  Metadt  Rel_Perf
 0 +     512       0         0

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02)
Critical Warning:                   0x00
Temperature:                        34 Celsius
Available Spare:                    100%
Available Spare Threshold:          10%
Percentage Used:                    9%
Data Units Read:                    54 799 914 [28,0 TB]
Data Units Written:                 37 073 270 [18,9 TB]
Host Read Commands:                 979 354 517
Host Write Commands:                500 449 183
Controller Busy Time:               24 859
Power Cycles:                       1 120
Power On Hours:                     9 849
Unsafe Shutdowns:                   728
Media and Data Integrity Errors:    0
Error Information Log Entries:      0
Warning  Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Critical Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Thermal Temp. 1 Transition Count:   2189
Thermal Temp. 1 Total Time:         37949

Warning: NVMe Get Log truncated to 0x200 bytes, 0x200 bytes zero filled
Error Information (NVMe Log 0x01, 16 of 256 entries)
No Errors Logged
```

pi@raspberrypi:/ $ cat /etc/fstab |grep /samba
/dev/disk/by-uuid/877a5afc-fc71-014f-bc05-5d459f5e9310 /samba                   ext4 rw,nofail,big_writes

Comment: Are you using the NVMe drive in an USB to NVMe adapter? But then using USB2 to connect to system? USB2 would be a huge bottleneck. Typically if using NVMe better to use USB-C or at least USB 3.2 Gen 2. Standard SATA SSD to USB works fine with USB3.

Comment: yes, i am using it in USB 3.0 powered HUB and in USB3.0 port of raspberry - at least description of this product claim to be 3.0 HUB

Comment: Does fstrim work on that setup?  It will complain if it doesn't.  USB enclosures need to support UASP (USB Attached SCSI Protocol) for TRIM to work.

Comment: I asked as I saw this: "Huasheng Electronics USB2.0 HUB"

Comment: sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda | grep “TRIM” shows nothing

Comment: this is the most interesting part \pi@raspberrypi:/ $ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/samba/tempfile bs=1M count=4096 conv=fdatasync,notrunc status=progress oflag=direct
skopiowane 1048576 bajtów (1,0 MB, 1,0 MiB), 17 s, **61,1 kB/s**